# How to get a value in bootstrapper with wix?

Tags: javascript, xml, wix

I'm working on an installer and specifically with the bootstrapper I'm trying to grab a path from a bundle.wxs I have setup. The bundle itself is just a bunch of property variables. In it, I have access to the path I need to get. However, I'm not sure how to get that path from the bundle. I have a localization file that I would ideally call to get the information, inferring that the localization file would be the one accessing the bundle to get the value. Anyone know how to do this nicely? I've attempted to use pre-processed variables to do it, but it hasn't worked so far.

Thanks!

Comment: Clarify your question, please. Where do you want to pass your path? To js code? When do you need to use it: during the process of installation or after it?

Comment: @SutarminAnton Sorry about that! Passing to the bootstrapper. I have a custom HyperLinkTheme.xml that has a text field that should show the path I want to be passed in to it. Since it's the bootstrapper, I've attempted to look into pre-processor variables, but everything I've tried so far hasn't worked. Thanks!